# Not able to "Clear" notifications from Astrid Tasks (an app)?

Tags: notifications, notification-bar

I am not able to clear notifications in the status bar for an app named Astrid Tasks.

Here is the screenshot: 
[image]

Why is it? I am sure that the app developer must have done this on purpose.

What should I do to get it back?

Can someone give me a link where I could read about these practices?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Astrid's `settings`, under `Reminder settings` there is an option to turn `Notification persistence` on or off. This determines whether or not notifications can be cleared with `Clear All` button.

Answer (score 1):

Astrid Tasks uses notifications that cannot be cleared by clicking on the "clear" button. Why they did this is a question only the Astrid developers can answer, but my guess is the people from Astrid want to remind you of a task until you actually finish it and/or change its status in Astrid.

By default notifications on Android can be cleared, but an app developer can choose to make a notification not-clearable (if you want technical details on how to do this, go [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html#FLAG_NO_CLEAR)). If there are any notifications that can be cleared, the clear button is enabled/visible but will not clear any non-clearable notifications when clicked.

Answer (score 0):

You can remove the notification by clicking on the notification and snoozing the task. The notifications is persistent so you can't accidentally be removed without having finished the task.

Answer (score -1):

Like THelper said.

There is no workaround for this as yet - so I am sorry to say that there is no way to remove the notification.

Comment: you can have just had this as a comment.